# c++ : threading variable declaration and affectation

Tags: c++, multithreading, variable-assignment

I've got this kind of c++ code in VS 2008:

```
int x function(int a, int b){
    int var1;
    int var2;
    var1*=a;
    var2*=b;
    return a+b;
}
```

How can I do this:

```
int x function(int a, int b){
    thread1 {
        int var1;
        var1*=a;
    }

    thread2{
        int var2;
        var2*=b;
    }

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    return a+b;
}
```

without creating 2 other functions ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. You don't initialize `var1` or `var2` to anything in particular, then you multiply them, and then you throw their values away. It doesn't really make any sense. In any event, the cost of dispatching work to a thread (or, orders of magnitude worse, joining one) is much higher than the cost of a single multiplication, so what would be the point of using a thread?

Comment: What does `int x function(int a, int b)` mean?

Comment: Know how [std::thread works here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) if that is all you're looking for.

Comment: I want to know if is it possible to assign 2 variables in two different threads without creating functions (just thread a part of c++ code).But David answers the question, cost of threading > assignement

Comment: I understand this is not real C++ code, but pseudo-code instead. So the question is if is there any way to create two threads without create two separate functions, am I right? mmm I think not, at least by using the POSIX functions or any external library I know, you must always create a function and call it through a thread-starting function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `std::future` is what you are after? but I am not sure it works for VS2008 though, it works for VS2012 btw:

```
int Function(int a, int b)
{
  std::future<int> a1 = std::async( [a](){ return a*2; } ); 
  std::future<int> b1 = std::async( [b](){ return b*3; } );

  return a1.get() + b1.get();
}
```

checkout reference of future: [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future)

Comment: I try to init my variables on each core of my computer, I'll try this.